# System Tray Network icon marked with red X, while all connections are fine!

Tags: windows-7, networking, icons, notification-area

On my Windows 7 Ultimate SP1 machine, the system tray network icon is showing with a big red X over it, even though all the network adapters and wireless dongles are working perfectly.

For appearance's sake I've hidden the icon, but I haven't figured out the root cause yet.

I believe it started when I was trying to install a Bluetooth USB dongle. I've removed all those drivers. On a side note, I also have issues with Windows 7 Resource Monitor: it will start but it won't show any data or statistics.

I've tried to reset the tray icon cache but this had no effect. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Could you post a screen shot of the icon? There are things other than network connections that can show an X. How many network connections do you have? You could have two Ethernet connections (a card and a motherboard connector) and multiple wireless (WiFi, 3G) connections available and be connected to the internet on one while another connection is not.

Comment: I've only got one NIC from my mobo, and a Wifi dongle that I randomly use, AKA plug in and pull out, It uses only one and the same USB. http://i55.tinypic.com/2uiaof7.png

Comment: In addition to Dour's answer: Check if you're looking at the right connection icon, since you mentioned you had a wireless dongle. The icon for your wireless dongle might look like a dial-up icon, if you're connecting through mobile broadband.

To check how many connections are enabled on your computer and to check which one is it you're connecting to, press **Win-R** > type **ncpa.cpl** and press **Enter**.

Comment: I've been there before, and it only shows my one working NIC that's installed. It's connected by cable modem.

Comment: Click on the icon, open the Network control panel, and look at your Active Networks. In each network, clock on Active Connections.

Comment: Sorry, Not sure what you mean. They are all working just fine. Yet the icon is marked with the red X! Thanks for trying tho.